# How to use C to store every character from a string as a number

Tags: c, arrays, string, io, scanf

Asssume that `getNumber` is 65432
I want to store the number to each arrays

Example:

```
number[0] = 6
number[1] = 5
number[2] = 4
```

How should I do?

```
char input[32];
char getNumber[32];
int number[20];
fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin);
sscanf(input,"%s",number);
```

Comment: You mean that `getNumber` contains the *string* `"65432"`?

Comment: There are many answers on similar questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are actually trying to do could look like this:

```
int digits[20];

char word[20];
sscanf(input, "%19s", word);       // <-- read word 

int i, len = strlen(word);
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    digits[i] = word[i] - '0';     // <-- get integral value of each character
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the first character in a string is at index `0`, the second at index `1`, etc. Then also remember that you can get the number from an [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) digit by subtracting `'0'` (look at the ASCII table to understand why).

So you can do it by doing e.g.

```
number[0] = getNumber[0] - '0';
number[1] = getNumber[1] - '0';
```

and so on.

This can of course be neatly done in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

first you can use `scanf` directelly to get your input string from stdin

```
scanf(" %19s", input);
```

and then you can save each digit from your input string in the number array in this way:

```
len = strlen(input);
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
   number[i] = input[i] - '0';
}
```